# "Invalid parameters" error when copying to another folder

Tags: windows, command-line, command-line-arguments

I have tried the following to copy the files in Data to another location but received the error "invalid parameters."  What is wrong with my command?

```
C:\xcopy c:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Data c:\DataBackUp
```

I have Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Your source folder needs to be enclosed in double-quotes like this:

```
C:\xcopy "c:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Data" c:\DataBackUp
```

Otherwise the XCOPY command sees the following as separate parameters:

- c:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server
- 5.7\Data
- c:\DataBackUp

It expects *two* paths, not three, hence the "Invalid parameters" error.

As a side note, it's only necessary to specify a path to XCOPY (e.g. `C:\xcopy`) if you really have a copy of the executable in the root of C: and intend to execute it from there. If not, just start your command with `XCOPY`.

Comment: Tks.  But, now I get this message : Does C:\DataBackUp specify a file name or directory name on target (F=file, D=directory)? and I just typed D.  And then a bunch of lines came out.  What should I do to ensure all the files in Data get copied into the DataBackUp folder?  Will windows 10 recognise that is a folder?

Comment: @KarenGoh add a back slash to the end of the destination path to tell XCOPY it's a folder, like this c:\DataBackUp\

Comment: Now, I have this SQLTable -hi5 and other tables inside but it is not copied.  And these are the things that I really make a copy.  How come Windows do not copy all these files into my DataBackUp  and only copied otheres like ibdata1?

Comment: @KarenGoh This sounds like you're facing a different problem. On this site we ask one question per problem, so please post a new question.